# Why do I get floating point error while generating a random number using G++?

Tags: c++, g++

I am using the G++ Compiler. The following code is getting compiled correctly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int random(int max)
    {
    return rand() / (RAND_MAX / max + 1);
    }

int main()
  {
    for(int iteration=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    int myNum=random(130);
    myNum=myNum-(myNum%iteration); /* This line causes exception. */
    (myNum<0)?(myNum=myNum*-1):myNum;
    cout<<"\nRandom number is "<<myNum<<"\n";
    }
  }
```

During runtime, it is generating the following exception..

```
g++ Implement.cc
./a.out
Floating point exception
```

Could you please help me to rectify this error?

Comment: You mean "why does my code fail to compile?" That line causes a compile error because `iteration` is not a declared variable.

Comment: @barnes53 A runtime error is occurring. You can see where the OP runs a.out.

Comment: @bames53 - He says it's being compiled correctly and shows a runtime output.  But code is missing. iteration is not defined in the code provided

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I see he typed in `g++ Implement.cc` and then `./a.out`, but he certainly did not successfully compile or run the program he posted.

Comment: And it's most likely the key to the problem the OP is having, so it should be here.

Comment: Does `iteration` start out at `0` by any chance?

Comment: There we go, expect answers now.

Comment: I had posted only a part of my code..

Comment: Hehe glad to start a trend...

Comment: (myNum<0)?(myNum=myNum*-1):myNum; // looks dodgy!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are taking `%` against 0

```
for(int iteration=0; i<10; i++)
                  ^^^
```